# Каким образом работает выражение S[0] = S[0] * 8; Переполнение[решен]

Tags: c++

Смысл такой, что в массив `int S[3]` передается значение, как я понимаю, стэка, т.е. каждый из элементов заполнен условным числом -858993460 (число взято из программы, но оно каждый раз разное, неизменным остается то, что оно отрицательное). При умножении на 8 оно становится положительным, аналогично условно, 1717986912. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Потому что результат умножения -6871947680 не влезает в 32-битный int и случается переполнение

Comment: Результат умножения не влезает в `int`. Это называется "переполнение". Переполнение знакового числа вызывает неопределенное поведение. Это если не учитывать неопределенное поведение от чтения неинициализированной переменной.

Comment: такое поведение не стандартизировано, и любой компилятор может вам вернуть любое число.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(-858993460 * 8) mod 2<sup>32</sup> ≡ 1717986912*.

Ваше сочетание компилятора и процессора считает целые значения по модулю *2<sup>32</sup>*.

В стандартном C++ такие вычисления вне закона. Программист обязан следить за тем чтобы промежуточные и окончательные значения в арифметических операциях не приводили к выходу за пределы диапазона `int` (в вашем случае *[-2<sup>31</sup>, 2<sup>31</sup> - 1]*). Иначе случается [неопределённое поведение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Грубо говоря, нет никаких гарантий относительно поведения программы, если случилось переполнение.

В конкретных реализациях C++ вы можете полагаться особенности компилятора. В данном случае программа вычисляет по модулю. Читайте документацию по конкретному компилятору, проверяйте сгенерированный машинный код (ассемблер).

**P.S.** Чтение неинициализированной переменной - тоже неопределённое поведение. Иногда вы прочтёте мусор, иногда ноль, иногда программа упадёт или начнёт вести себя непредсказуемо. Проверяйте машинный код или следуйте стандарту.

**P.P.S.** Следуйте стандарту.